# How to split these strings into an array

Tags: c++, split

I'm looking for a method to split the following line of text into an array.

> **Here is some text\r\n"here is another line"\r\nAnd another line**

Such that the resultant array is:

> **Here is some text**
>
> **\r\n**
>
> **"**
>
> **here is another line**
>
> **"**
>
> **\r\n**
>
> **And another line**

Note there are essentially two delimeters here, **"** and **\r\n**.
I need to do this in C++ and there could be additional delimeters in the future.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: No, this is not homework.

Here's what I have so far:

```
const RWCString crLF = "\r\n";
const RWCString doubleQuote = "\"";


    RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString> Split(const RWCString &value, const RWCString &specialContent)
    {
        RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString> result;
    
        unsigned index = 0;
    
        RWCString str = value;
    
        while ( ( index = str.index( specialContent, 0, RWCString::ignoreCase ) ) != RW_NPOS )
        {
            RWCString line = str(0, index);
    
            result.append(line);
            result.append(specialContent);
    
            str = str(index, str.length() - index);
            str = str(specialContent.length(), str.length() - specialContent.length());
        }
    
        if (str.length() > 0)
        {
            result.append(str);
        }
    
        return result;
    }
    
        void replaceSpecialContents(const RWCString &value)
        {
        
            RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString> allStrings;
        
            RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString> crLFStrings = Split(value, crLF);
        
            for (unsigned i=0; i<crLFStrings.entries(); i++)
            {
            RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString> dqStrings = Split(crLFStrings[i], doubleQuote);
        
                if (dqStrings.entries() == 1)
                {
                    allStrings.append(crLFStrings[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (unsigned j=0; j<dqStrings.entries(); j++)
                    {
                        allStrings.append(dqStrings[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
    
    }
```

Comment: What approaches have you tried already?

Comment: Basically, you want to split it into token (although token usually aren't whole lines). In order to tokenize input, you need a lexer.

Comment: Be careful with '\r\n'. On some platforms this is the line termination sequence. Thus if you open a file in text mode (default) these two characters will be converted into a single '\n' character (on some platforms). Also Note: conversely the '\n' character is converted into the line termination sequence when written to a file (that is opened in text mode).

Comment: `RWTValOrderedVector`: Just wondering, what's unordered vector?

Comment: @ybungalobill - `RWTValVector<T>` which, sadly has restrictions on methods.  E.g., there is no `append` as the class assumes constant length for the life of the vector.  There is a `reshape` so you _can_ do an append if you work for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it that will work in C and C++:

```
//String to tokenize:
char str[] = "let's get some tokens!";

//A set of delimiters:
char delims[] = " ";

//List of tokens:
char *tok1 = NULL,
     *tok2 = NULL,
     *tok3 = NULL;

//Tokenize the string:
tok1 = strtok(str, delims);
tok2 = strtok(NULL, delims); //after you get the first token
tok3 = strtok(NULL, delims); //supply "NULL" as first strtok parameter
```

You can modify this is various ways.  You can put all "strtok(NULL, delims)" calls in a loop to make it more flexible, you can interface with C++ string using .c_str(), etc.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this, but it doesn't include the tokens

Answer (score 1):

`getline` has an optional delimiter, so you can use `stringstream` to do it with very little effort on your part.  The downside is that (I believe) it only works with one delimiter at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Bissect the problem as follows:

1. I have a pointer to substring. How to find the next substring?
2. I have a pointer to substring. How do I add it as the next element to array?

Now, solve 1 and 2. If any problem, ask again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string::find_first_of`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/) and [`string::substr`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/). Just be careful to check for "empty" strings; `find_first_of` will find `char`s, so `\r` and `\n` will both be split off by the resulting algorithm.

Alternatively, iterate over the whole string, and copy the previous part when you come across another delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

A really simple way is to just use flex:
You can build a really simpler lexer for a C++ application in a few lines that is very readable.

#### Note:

I would note that you should be careful with '\r\n'. If you open a file in text mode (the default) then the standard stream reading will convert the standard line termination sequence into a '\n'. On some platforms the end of line termination sequence is '\r\n' and thus if you read a stream from a file you may only see a '\n' character.

#### split.lex

```
%option c++
%option noyywrap
%%
\"           return 1;
\r\n         return 2;
[^"\r\n]*    return 3;
%%
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "FlexLexer.h"

int main()
{
    yyFlexLexer     lexer(&std::cin, &std::cout);
    int             token;

    while((token = lexer.yylex()) != 0)
    {
        std::string  tok(lexer.YYText(), lexer.YYText() + lexer.YYLeng());
        std::cout << "Token: " << token << "(" << tok << ")\n";
    }
}
```

#### Build

```
% flex split.lex
% g++ main.cpp lex.yy.cc
```

#### Run (on pre-pared file)

```
% cat testfile | ./a.exe
Token: 3(Here is some text)
Token: 2(
)
Token: 1(")
Token: 3(here is another line)
Token: 1(")
Token: 2(
)
Token: 3(And another line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the Rogue Wave SourcePro API you're using, you could use RWTRegex to split the string into tokens:

```
RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString> tokenize(const RWCString& str)
{
    RWTRegex<char> re("\\r\\n|\"|([^\"\\r]|\\r[^\\n])*|\\r$");

    RWTRegex<char>::iterator it(re, str);

    RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString> result;
    for (; it != RWTRegex<char>::iterator(); ++it) {
        result.append(it->subString(str));
    }
    return result;
}
```

For details on RWTRegex see http://www.roguewave.com/Portals/0/products/sourcepro/docs/12.0/html/sourceproref/classRWTRegex.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that uses TR1 regex features.

```
std::string text("Here is some text\r\n\"here is another line\"\r\nAnd another line");
std::vector<std::string> vec;

std::regex rx("[\\w ]+|\\r\\n|\"");
std::sregex_iterator rxi(text.begin(), text.end(), rx), rxend;

for (; rxi != rxend; ++rxi)
{
    vec.push_back(rxi->str());
}
```

In my testing, this populates the vector with the 7 substrings in your example. I'm no expert so there may be a more correct regular expression than the one I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

strtok will replace your tokens with NULL. That's why it does not include the tokens.

man strtok for more information. I'm also playing around with strtok and strtok_r as I have incoming char array of the following

Hello~Milktea~This is my message\r\nMessage~I have a good watch~Cartier\r\n

I am going to first strip the ~ (tildes) followed by the \r\n, or vice versa.